# strtotime alternative in php 5.1.6

Tags: php, datetime

I am successfully using following strtotime command with PHP 5.3

```
echo strtotime('last day of last month');
```

but unfortunately same command return empty value in PHP 5.1.6 I don't want to upgrade PHP as PHP 5.1.6 is default version in CentOs 5. I wonder if is there any altertive method to get same result in PHP 5.1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date("t/m/Y", strtotime("last month"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should to the trick, mate :D

```
strtotime('-1 second',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))
```

If you echo this as a date you'd get 02/28/2011.